# How to relocate packages in maven test phase?

Tags: maven, automated-tests, packaging, maven-shade-plugin

I have 2 dependencies which are notorious for having conflict with each other: Apache Spark & json4s.

Detail of which is described, but not conclusively, in this this json4s issue:

https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/274

I prefer the simple and brutal solution: to add my own json4s dependencies and relocate them whenever there is a JAR hell:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${assembly.jar.dir}/${assembly.jar.basename}</outputFile>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <relocations>
                          <relocation>
                             <pattern>org.json4s</pattern>
                             <shadedPattern>org.my-project.json4s</shadedPattern>
                          </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this plugin only affects package phase, which is preceded by test phase, which doesn't benefit from relocation at all. As a result, maven test frequently throws false alarms that doesn't affect packaged all-inclusive JAR at all, and/or fails to detect errors caused by relocation.

I'm looking for a consistent suite of maven plugins, that can guarantee that package relocating & class loading sequence are identical regardless if the java program is being tested by maven or if the java program is packaged and deployed in production. This seems to be a simple and dull task for maven build model that should exist for a long time. However, when I search for 'maven relocation'. I can only find limited resources, most of which referring to maven-shade plugin.

So what should I do to reliably solve this problem and make maven test truly useful? (what's the point of testing if it's unrelated to your production program?) If there is no out-of-the-box solution, how hard is it to write my own maven plugin?

**PS**: I have attempted to migrate my build toolchain to OSGI, but turns out that it is much less maintained and causes a different set of bugs and maintenance cost. So I eventually gave up and fall back to maven.

Comment: If you rely on the packaging you need to run your tests as integration tests in the integration-test phase instead of the test phase. Furthermore what do you mean by: `As a result, maven test frequently throws false alarms that doesn't affect packaged all-inclusive JAR at all, and/or fails to detect errors caused by relocation.`. What are you testing there?

Comment: maven test doesn't relocate, packaged JAR does relocate, this creates a discrepancy between java classes, hence some new error appears and some old error disappear.

Comment: Speaking of integration test, it can't be used since 1. its a multi-module project & the maven-shade plugin is only used in the final module, very few tests can be conducted at that point. 2. The class loading sequence of spark is completely different from the class loading sequence of java application, so it still won't guarantee success.

Comment: The integration can be done to depend on the maven-shade part and furthermore the integration tests can be done as a separate module which depends on the appropriate modules.